Looking for a chess puzzle
I recall seeing this chess puzzle in a historic puzzle book that had many different types of puzzles, one each of each genre. The puzzle had a very unusual setup and the challenge was to find the one move that wasn't checkmate.
Does anyone know which puzzle I am referring to?

Yes. Any problem chess fan knows this offhand, although I must say that
this is only the most famous rendering (I myself composed
a problem with this stipulation, but another trick), so there is a 10% chance it wasn't this one:
By Karl Fabel 1952

It was this. Thanks!

I'd love to see yours, if you'd post a link

H.R., Inselschach 1982 (my club zine), 4B3/2p1p1p1/2P1k1P1/4P3/3PKP2/3PpP2/8/8 not mate in 1 move, solution in rot13 encoding: Abg Xkr3 - vg vf rnfl gb frr Oynpx unq ab ynfg zbir. Guhf r2.
